# Confidence interval of the expected value

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval

Is this possible to compute?

From a normal distribution we took a sample  $( 11, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 17, 18).$ Compute the $98 \%$ confidence interval of the expected value.

I'm studying statistics on my own but I don't know what formula should I use here.

Comment: Can you parametrize the stated normal distribution in terms of this expected value?

Comment: Most samples from normal distributions do not give integers only

Comment: I think that it is a textbook question, which sometimes gives this type of information claiming it to be normal, especially if it is a social science statistics book...

Comment: @tomka in spite of such assertions by some textbooks, a collection of small integer outcomes aren't from a normal distribution, except as a very rough approximation to the actual cdf.

Comment: I wasn't claiming that it is OK to do so, I was explaining why/how the OP might have come up with this flawed exercise. In fact I was sarcstic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add the tag self-study to your question.

First estimate the expectation of the normal distribution by the sample mean, then the sample variance, and the square root of the sample variance.

```
> x<-c(11,13,13,14,14,14,15,15,17,18)
> mean(x); var(x)
[1] 14.4
[1] 4.044444
> sqrt(var(x))
[1] 2.01108
```

The confidence interval is contructed from this information. Hint: its upper limit is `mean(x)+qt(0.99,df=n-1)*sqrt(var(x))/sqrt(n)`.

Comment: The OP may never have seen R code. You'd be better placed to give relevant formulae first, and then at the very least *explain* that you're using R. Even if the OP has seen it, some later readers won't have.

Comment: So I got x<-c(11,13,13,14,14,14,15,15,17,18)
mean(x)+qt(0.99,df=10-1)*sqrt(var(x))/sqrt(10)
mean(x)-qt(0.99,df=10-1)*sqrt(var(x))/sqrt(10)

[1] 16.19432 [1] 12.60568 . Is this correct?

Comment: This looks good!